# How do I open BSD System Calls Manual instead of BSD General Commands Manual?

Tags: osx, man

Suppose I wish to read about `wait` syscall. Typing `man wait` would only give the manual entry for wait as in shell, not in syscall. However if I type `man waitpid`, I would get the manual entry for `wait` as they are inside the same page.

How do I specify which manual entry is desired in a case like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the section as the first argument to man:

```
man wait
man 1 wait
```

These will open the `BSD General Commands Manual` for `wait`

```
man 2 wait
```

This will open the `BSD System Calls Manual` for `wait`

That's why you often see the number in parens after the command, e.g. `wait (1)` and `wait (2)`.

*Note: I tested this in FreeBSD but it should be the same on MacOSX or pretty much any POSIX OS, like Linux, Solaris etc.*

Answer (score 1):

When you type `man waitpid`, notice how in the upper left (and right) corners, you see *e.g.* "wait(2)".  That "(2)" indicates the man page *section*, and this is what you'd use, *e.g.*:

```
$ man 2 wait
```

By specifying the section you want `man` to search *first*, you can by-pass things like shell documentation.  Wikipedia talks more about the various man page sections [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections).